# Ask for donations vs ask for investments

Tags: copywriting, wording

I have created this site: https://crypto4ngo.org

Project pages at the site ask to buy tokens (our own new cryptocurrency) by sending Ether (a kind of cryptocurrency) to a certain Ethereum address.

I want to add listing BitCoin addresses for project pages.

So we have: Ether donations are rewarded with tokens send back to one who paid. BitCoin donations are not rewarded by the system.

Now: How should I ask for donations or for investments? Should I ask the user to donate or to invest (in the case of Ethereum addresses)? Should I ask him to *donate* BitCoin but *invest* with Ether? or should I ask just to *donate* (and be rewarded)?

The thing I want: A clear wording at the top of the project page which maximizes the sum of BitCoin and Ether payments to us.

I am awaiting both ideas how to ask BitCoin donations (which are not yet asked at this site) and how to improve existing plea for Ethereum investments.

This is an example of a project page: https://crypto4ngo.org/project/view/1

Also note that this Ethereum investment follows [a certain formula](https://crypto4ngo.org/docs/contract#formula). Where to put this formula (or a link to it) to attract investors?

Comment: Have you also considered the legal ramifications of this? If you run afoul of Securities Laws you can be shut down or worse. I would first do a deep dive about the implications of your currency, and if donations or token sales (or a mix) put you at legal risk. If you sort that out, you'll know what you should say.

Comment: If you get something of value in exchange for a donation, it's not a donation. If you don't get anything for an investment, it's not an investment. Maybe go for a third option, like "contribute to project" or "support project"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about *donating* Bitcoin (noun: *donation*) and *paying for*/*buying* your currency with Ether (noun: *payment*)?

Answer (score 4):

**Please read the whole answer, especially the last part!**

**User Experience Viewpoint:**
*A donation* in the microcopy way is something you do out of charity or generosity. It is not awarded with huge give-backs but, unlike stated in the comments, **can** give you something in exchange. Mostly it would be the name in the credits, a pen or maybe just a meeting with the PR/Founder. **Short:** I give you something, I don't need something back.

*An investment* is a investment. You pay in a certain pre-defined amount in exchange for some shares and have the chance to sell off these shares based on the investment contract. **Short:** I give you something, now give me back what we agreed on.

**Law Viewpoint:**
Please do contact a lawyer if you consider taking donations or let people invest in your project. Both terms are regulated and defined in about every single (western) country by law. Taking "donations" and giving people something back might qualify as sale. Investments are especially regulated by money laundering laws.